# Полупрозрачный toolbar

Tags: java, android

Как можно сделать полупрозрачный toolbar черного цвета хотелось бы как в quickPick 
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
//установить прозрачность фону от 0 (прозрачно) до 255 (непрозрачно).
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(125);
```

или [так](http://www.hrupin.com/2013/05/how-to-setalpha-for-view-in-android-2-3-api-10-and-lower) (для старых версий андроида, API<=10):

```
setAlphaForView(toolbar, 0.5f);

private void setAlphaForView(View v, float alpha)
{
    AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(alpha, alpha);
    animation.setDuration(0); 
    animation.setFillAfter(true); 
    v.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Таким образом не надо доп. цвета в ресурсы пихать и можно менять прозрачность динамически (например делать Toolbar прозрачным при скролле).

Answer (score 2):

`toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color))`

Comment: интересует значение my_color

Comment: откуда то в ресурсах появилось значение   <color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color> он подходит

Comment: @YeldosTanikin любой свой цвет можно задать в `color.xml`, или использовать этот `black_overlay`.  Цвет задается в формате `AARRGGBB` где AA - это альфа, прозрачность, RGB - Red, Green, Blue. Значения любой компоненты меняются от 00 до FF. Например 00000000 это черный полностью прозрачный, FF000000 это черный полностью непрозрачный.

Comment: меня интересовало только код для такого цвета, спасибо, откуда то такой цвет взялся в ресурсах он подходит и я его применяю.